# Connect to Chromecast using Remote Display API with WiFi Direct

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, android-cast-api

In the [official android documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote) it says - "With the remote display APIs, your sender app can now render **directly** to any Cast receiver, like a Chromecast". What does **directly** mean here? Does it mean no wifi media channel is required/i.e. the chromecast device and the phone/tablet don't need to be on the same wifi network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the do need to be on the same wifi network. Remote Display enables you to have a View in your Android app on your phone and mirror that view on your chromecast screen.

Comment: So this means I cannot connect to a chrome cast device using the WiFi direct tech?

Comment: Correct, you cannot.